# Get level discounts algorithm

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I have a requirement, the user has a base count his own, and will buy more count products.

I have a discount system:

```
var b1 = { min: 1, max: 5, discount: 0.01 }
var b2 = { min: 6, max: 10, discount: 0.02 }
var b3 = { min: 11, max: 15, discount: 0.03 }
var b4 = { min: 16, max: 20, discount: 0.04 }

var b = [b1, b2, b3, b4]   // this is the discount system
```

there is a requirement, should be a `get_discounts` method, through it I can get the new buy products' discounts.

like this:

```
var a = 5  // this is the base count for user own.
console.log(get_discount(a, 7, b))  // the 7 is new buy. I want to get the discounts of the 7

// [
//   { count: 2, discount: 0.03 }  // 11, 12 ( 11  <= a + 7 <=15 )
//   { count: 5, discount: 0.02 }  //  ( 6  <= a + 7 <=10 )
// ]
// there exclude the `1 -> 5` (exclude the `a` for discount) . the list counts are 2, 5 (2+5 = 7)
```

I tried my way:

```
function get_discount(a , new_count, b) {

  var discounts = []

  var tem_count = a + new_count

  for(index in b){

    var item = b[index]

    if (tem_count >= item.min && tem_count <= item.max){

      var discount_obj = {
        count: tem_count - item.min + 1,
        disocunt: item.discount
      }

      tem_count -= discount_obj.count

      return discount_obj
    }
  }

}
```

I only get the

```
{ count: 2, disocunt: 0.03 }
```

There was an obvious problem, not the desired effect.

Who can help to optimize the function?

Comment: Spelling *really* matters in programming, you should fix your mistakes now before they become even more confusing later.

Comment: Also, what is `item.min`?

Comment: I write the code just for test, so it maybe not that readable.

Comment: the discount function should just take two parameters. first is the number of items, regardless of what's currently owned or what's newly added. It's up to the *caller* to pass in the sum. instead of calling the second parameter "b", it should be called "rates", as it's the rates table you are passing in.

Comment: `5 + 7 = 12`. the `11, 12` is included in `b3`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`Array#reduceRight`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduceRight).

```js
function getDiscount(offset, amount, table) {
    var value = offset + amount;
    return table.reduceRight((r, { min, max, discount }) => {
        var count = value - min + 1;
        if (value > amount && min <= value && value <= max) {
            r.push({ count, discount });
            value -= count;
        }
        return r;
    }, []);
}

var discounts = [{ min: 1, max: 5, discount: 0.01 }, { min: 6, max: 10, discount: 0.02 }, { min: 11, max: 15, discount: 0.03 }, { min: 16, max: 20, discount: 0.04 }],
    oldBuy = 5,
    newBuy = 7,
    discount = getDiscount(oldBuy, newBuy, discounts);

console.log(discount);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the while-loop for calculate the new buy count:

```js
var b1 = { min: 1, max: 5, discount: 0.01 }
var b2 = { min: 6, max: 10, discount: 0.02 }
var b3 = { min: 11, max: 15, discount: 0.03 }
var b4 = { min: 16, max: 20, discount: 0.04 }

var b = [b1, b2, b3, b4]

function get_discount_by_itemcount(tem_count, b) {
  for(index in b){

    var item = b[index]

    if (tem_count >= item.min && tem_count <= item.max){

      var discount_obj = {
        count: tem_count - item.min + 1,
        disocunt: item.discount
      }

      tem_count -= discount_obj.count

      return {
        discount_obj: discount_obj,
        tem_count: tem_count
      }
    }
  }
}

function get_discount(a , new_count, b) {

  var discounts = []

  var tem_count = a + new_count

  while( tem_count > a){

    var obj = get_discount_by_itemcount(tem_count, b)
    tem_count = obj.tem_count
    discounts.push(obj.discount_obj)

  }

  return discounts
}

var a = 5
console.log(get_discount(a, 7, b))
```